# Having issues with an array and if statment in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a program that has a array of 100 doors. I made an array which might not be correct. I want all 100 doors to be read as closed.

For this, I made `c = closed` and `o = open`. My problem is with the if statement.

I want the first statement to start on the second door and go up by every 2, like so

```
2 4 6 8
```

and so on. Each time it gets to a door, it needs to open it. Then I need another if statement that goes by threes `ie 3 6 9 12` and so on,

When it gets to a door, it need to close open doors and open closed doors. The issue I have is how do I get the if statment to look at every 2 in the list and every 3?

```
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Locker</title>
<script>
    var lockers = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
                   c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
                   c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
                   c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
                   c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c];
    var c = closed
    var o = open

    function everyTwo(openlockers){
</script>
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: This looks an awful lot like a homework assignment?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

Comment: ... A string `c` is expressed as `"c"`. Some JS basics might be in order before going much further; it seems like you're just typing stuff at random hoping it'll work.

Comment: for(var  i = 0; i < yourarray.length; i + 2) iterates over every second one. Figure the other one out by yourself

Comment: I can only recommend learning the basics of javascript before asking for help with something like this. As mentions above your array is incorrect and var c and o's values should be wrapped in single/double quotes and end with a semicolon **and** you haven't closed your `everyTwo` function.  All this before getting to answer your question.... I wish you the very best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### JS Fiddle Demo

```
// Boolean. If true, the door is open, if false, it is closed
var o = false,
    lockers = [o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o,
               o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o,
               o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o,
               o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o,
               o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o, o],
    count = lockers.length;

function everyN(n){
    for(var i=n-1; i<count; i+=n){
        // reverse the state (open / closed)
        lockers[i] = !lockers[i];
    }
}
```

Use the `everyN(n)` function with the number you want (2 or 3 for example):

```
// custom function to display the lockers (See in JS Fiddle)
displayLockers('Initial state');
everyN(2);
displayLockers('Every Two');
everyN(2);
displayLockers('Every Two + Every Two = Initial state');
everyN(3);
displayLockers('Every Three');
everyN(2);
displayLockers('Every Three + Every Two');
```

Comment: i was wondering if there was anyway i could contact you i am struggeling and could use some advice?

Comment: @WayneJenkins Sure, you can come over here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72442/open-lockers

Comment: sadly i can not chat there due to my low rep

Comment: @WayneJenkins hmm, any other alternatives? **Edit**: Here: http://tinychat.com/cv31ll

Answer (score 0):

a script that lets you choose per call which lockers you open/close .. changes open to close and vice versa ..

```
<script>
    var c = "closed";
    var o = "open";
    var lockers = [c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
        c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
        c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
        c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c,
        c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c, c];
    function openLockers(lockerArray,interval) {
        var newArray = lockerArray;
        for (var i = 0; i <= (newArray.length - 1); i++) {
            if ((i+1) % interval === 0) {
                newArray[i] = (newArray[i] == c) ? newArray[i] = o : newArray[i] = c;
            }
        }
        return newArray;
    };
    lockers = openLockers(lockers,2);
</script>
```

Not sure if that's what you were going for or not .. I presumed that you would want to run the function on multiple iterations on the same data.

Answer (score 0):

First you should know that you have to define a variable, before it can be used in an Array, so `c` in your `lockers` Array would contain a bunch of `undefined` values. Here's what you are probably looking for.

```
function openLockers(lockerCount, start, every){
  var l = lockerCount, a = [];
  for(var i=0; i<l; i++){
    a[i] = false;
  }
  for(var i=start; i<l; i+=every){
    a[i] = true;
  }
  return a;
}
// 100 lockers open every 2 starting at Array element 1, which is the second Array element
var lockers = openLockers(100, 1, 2);
```

`true` values in the `lockers` Array represent open lockers while `false` values represent closed lockers. Note that `start` is an Array number.